# Print a sequence of n^n using do while

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

Print a sequence of n^n for 1 to 15. This code only prints out 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int i, n;

    i = 0;
    n=1;

    do {
        n = n^n;
        cout << n;
        n++;
        i++;

    }while(i<15);

    return 0;
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question as asked, but you'll need to add `endl` to that cout statement so your numbers don't jumble up on the same line (unless that is what you wanted to happen ).

Comment: [Arithmetic operators in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: Note that on some chipsets `a XOR a` where `a` is a register is a faster way of setting the register to 0 rather than an assignment.

Comment: You are possibly confused about what the `^` operator does. It is not an exponentiation operator (C++ doesn't have one of those)! Rather it is an **exclusive or** (bitwise) operator - and any number XORed with itself is zero.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd expect a compiler for that platform to know that and produce an XOR operation for such an assignment. Point being you should still write an assignment, because that's the meaning of your program

Comment: @RTHarston Why would you pay for a flush if you don't need it? Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Good point, thanks for the reminder. I only suggested `std::endl` since Michael wasn't already using a string literal that he could easily add the `\n` to (not that "\n" is any harder to add then std::endl, I just personally prefer the second for cleanliness when not already using a string literal). I completely forgot about the flush (still a bit new with C++), I'll look into that a bit more. 